# Closing the lid isn't toggeling standby anymore after update in Lubuntu. How can I fix that?

Tags: lubuntu, power-management

On my netbook closing the lid only leads to lock screen and not to standby in Lubuntu. That happened after the update on 11. 0.

In 11.04 that worked without problem. Also, in 11. 10 Ubuntu (Unity) closing the lid leads to standby.

So how can I achieve the same in Lubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Right click on the battery icon on the taskbar.
2. Select 'Preferences' from the resulting menu (which should bring up the XFCE4 Power Manager Preferences).
3. Set the desired action to perform when the laptop lid is closed ('suspend' = 'standby' I think). Make sure you set the desired action for both 'On AC' and 'On Battery'.

NOTE: If you don't have a battery icon on the taskbar you can access the 'XFCE4 Power Manager Preferences' from Menu --> Preferences --> Power Manager

If you do not have a 'Power Manager' entry under the 'Preferences' menu, follow amjjawad's excellent advice from [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1867740) thread over on ubuntuforums.org.

In a terminal type:

```
sudo leafpad /usr/share/applications/xfce4-power-manager-settings.desktop
```

Replace this line:

```
OnlyShowIn=XFCE;
```

With (add a # before the line):

```
#OnlyShowIn=XFCE;
```

Save the file and 'Power Manager' should now be in Menu --> Preferences.

Comment: You may also need to install the power manager, `sudo apt-get install xfce4-power-manager`

Answer (score 3):

I am using gdm and xfce (ubuntu 11.04). Gdm greeter cannot perform suspend without gnome-power-manager present. I prefer xfce power manager. Having both power managers present resulted in problems.

Adding file: /etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.pre will force suspend (via pm-suspend) always when lid is closed:

```
#!/bin/bash
# TODO:  Change the above to /bin/sh

grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
   pm-suspend
   exit  
fi
```

Comment: Per @Sean - *"qwertypoke's script is a good work around, just remember to make the script executable."*

Comment: To make the script executable, run `sudo chmod +x /etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.pre`. (@qwertypoke You might want to add this or similar information to your answer ...unless for some reason it's not necessary to make the script executable ...I think it is necessary.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Lubuntu 18.04 and the configuration is under Preferences -> Power Management. The window that pops up has the name Xfce Power Manager. The setting is on the General Tab.

I'm ashamed to say I wish I had looked there sooner instead of spending a couple hours on this.

Comment: Isn't this what the accepted answers says?

Comment: More or less but for a later version. The window title has changed since this question was originally answered.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences - LXQt Settings - Power management - LID

you need to set:
On Battery = Suspend
On Ac = Suspend

by default it has settings that does nothin on lid closed.